# Sticky header on scroll in vuetify datatable

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

When vuetify datatable height is greater than the window height, when we scroll the page, I want the header row sticky till the datatable scroll is over

The behaviour should be similar to this
https://output.jsbin.com/zuzuqe/1/

also like the datatable they used https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

I've also tried

```
th {
    position:sticky;  
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

The position sticky is relative to the datatable and not to the window

Can anyone suggest me some idea or codepen on how to implement the same using Vuetify datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a Vue Component [Float Thead vue component](https://github.com/tmlee/vue-floatThead)

EDIT : 
This is vue directive usable with vuetify `v-simple-table`

Use :

```
<v-simple-table v-simple-table-sticky></v-simple-table>
```

Directive :

```
function stickyScrollHandler(el) {
    return () => {
        const getOffsetTop = function(element) {
            let offsetTop = 0;
            while (element) {
                offsetTop += element.offsetTop;
                element = element.offsetParent;
            }
            return offsetTop;
        }

        const table = el.querySelector("table");
        const tableHeader = el.querySelector(".adx-table_sticky_header");
        let tableHeaderFloat = el.querySelector(".adx-table_sticky--float");

        const pos = getOffsetTop(table) - window.scrollY;

        if (pos < 0) {
            if (!tableHeaderFloat) {
                const clone = tableHeader.cloneNode(true);
                clone.classList.remove('.table_sticky_header');

                tableHeaderFloat = document.createElement('table');
                tableHeaderFloat.appendChild(clone);
                tableHeaderFloat.classList.add("adx-table_sticky--float");
                table.parentNode.appendChild(tableHeaderFloat);

                tableHeader.style.opacity = 0;
            }

            if (Math.abs(pos) < table.offsetHeight - tableHeaderFloat.offsetHeight) {
                tableHeaderFloat.style.position = "absolute";
                tableHeaderFloat.style.top = Math.abs(pos) + "px";
            }
        } else {
            if (tableHeaderFloat) {
                tableHeaderFloat.remove();
            }

            tableHeader.style.opacity = 1;
        }
    }
}

Vue.directive("simple-table-sticky", {
    bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
        el.querySelector("table thead").classList.add("adx-table_sticky_header");
        el.style.position = "relative"

        window.addEventListener('scroll', stickyScrollHandler(el));
    },
    unbind: function(el) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', stickyScrollHandler(el));
    }
});
```

Comment: This a different library, I've already implemented all the features of datatable using vuetify datatable. Using vuetify itself, if there is any css fixes, please suggest. That would be really helpful to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

There is `fixed-header` props in `data table` UI component of `Vuetify`. Checkout it -> https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#api

Comment: fixed-header can be used only to make the header row fixed inside the datatable level. It will not fix on scroll the page, check this demo https://output.jsbin.com/zuzuqe/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is OK, since you correctly apply stickiness to `<th>` element. However, the issue is that Vuetify.js data table wrapper has overflow. It can be removed by `/deep/` selector:

```
.v-data-table /deep/ .v-data-table__wrapper {
  overflow: unset;
}
```

Here's a complete working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sticky-vuetify-table-header-3o0km

I wrote a little article explaining my solution to this problem: https://medium.com/@jareklipski/sticky-table-header-in-vuetify-js-fab39988dc3

Answer (score 0):

A combination of previous answers worked for me:

Unsetting overflow on the table wrapper as suggested by loomchild:

```
:deep(div.v-table__wrapper) {
  overflow: unset
}
```

And adding fixed-header to the component, as suggested by Enkhtulga (no need to set position/top on thead in this case, this prop takes care of it):

```
<v-data-table fixed-header>
```